# Linking Button to Next View Controller

Tags: ios, ipad

I can't seem to figure out for xcode 6 how you would connect a button to go to the next view controller. In the view controller scene, I have 2 view controllers, VC1 and VC2. VC1 has a button and I want VC1 to be first, and then have the user click the button, which will lead it to VC2. How do I do that? Basically, how do I link the button in VC1 to VC2?

Answer (score 1):

Just Press control key and drag your UIButton onto another view controller

[image: Transition between twio views]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + drag from your button to the next controller in the storyboard. Choose "present modally".

Learn about UINavigationViewController, it's maybe more what you're looking for.